# Count text matches in an Excel worksheet where two other cells on the same row match a value

Tags: excel

I have a table of data in Excel with the name of the player in position 1, position 2, the map played on and the winner.

I am creating a table which counts how many wins were by the player in position 1 and position 2 for each map. That means looking at a column of data for a matching map name, then where it matches seeing if the position 1 cell matches the winner cell, and if so increasing the win count by 1, with a separate cell doing the same thing for position 2. It should look at the full range of data, and output the result into a cell on another worksheet.

The problem is while I know how to check for text matches in a range, I don't know how to check for the match and then perform another check on the same row for a whole range of data. Do I need an intermediary worksheet to achieve this, or is it possible to write a single cell formula which does it?

Comment: A screenshot or sample data, along with the expected result, would be very helpful to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided your data so I created basic example that accomplishes what you want. This is all shown on one sheet just for simplicity of the answer but you can easily modify this to change the formula to a different sheet.

See below example, top table is sample data and bottom table is the "Summary" table you desire.

The formula in cell `B11` is dragged down to cell `C13`.

```
= SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$7=$A11)*
  (INDEX($A$2:$B$7,0,MATCH(B$10,$A$1:$B$1,0))=$D$2:$D$7))
```

[image]